# ClassCastException trouble in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hello I have implemented `MyAsyncHttpRequest` Task as `AsyncTask` as follows

```
public class MyAsyncHttpRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList> {

    private Activity activity;
    private AsyncTaskCompleteListener callback;     
    private SessionManager session;

    public MyAsyncHttpRequest(Activity act, SessionManager session ) {
        try {
            Log.i("TAG", "MyAsyncHttpRequest::Constructor");
            this.activity = act;
            this.callback = (AsyncTaskCompleteListener)act; // Just here crashes all!!!
            this.session  = session;

    } catch ( Exception exc ) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }

    ... // More Stuff

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (null != dialog && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }


        // Obviously, if callback couldn't be assigned in Constructor, here crashes too
        callback.onTaskComplete(result, cmd);
    }
}
```

And

The public Interface `AsyncTaskCompleteListener` like this

```
public interface AsyncTaskCompleteListener {    
    public void onTaskComplete(ArrayList list, int cmd);
}
```

and the activity where I call the `MyAsyncHttpRequest` like this

```
public class WmsMapActivity extends Activity implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        ...
        myMethod();

    }

    private myMethod() {
        ...
        myAsyncHttpRequest = new MyAsyncHttpRequest(this, session); // It crashes here before I do "myAsynHttpRequest.execute(...);"             
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete(ArrayList list, int cmd){
        ... // Some stuff
    }
}
```

My Logcat is just below and it says, my Activity can't be cast to `AsyncTaskCompleteListener`

```
com.nutiteq.advancedmap.activity.WmsMapActivity cannot be cast to com.utils.AsyncTaskCompleteListener
```

This approach worked fine until today morning but now I get this Exception.

***May anyone tell me what is wrong in my Code?***

Thank you very much.

```
09-22 11:19:05.314: I/TAG(9310): MyAsyncHttpRequest::Constructor
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310): java.lang.ClassCastException:com.nutiteq.advancedmap.activity.WmsMapActivity cannot be cast to com.XXX.utils.AsyncTaskCompleteListener
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at com.XXX.utils.MyAsyncHttpRequest.<init>(MyAsyncHttpRequest.java:54)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at com.nutiteq.advancedmap.activity.WmsMapActivity.tryToListFarms(WmsMapActivity.java:1349)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at com.nutiteq.advancedmap.activity.WmsMapActivity.buildGroupListFromServer(WmsMapActivity.java:1368)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at com.nutiteq.advancedmap.activity.WmsMapActivity.onCreate(WmsMapActivity.java:476)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-22 11:19:05.324: W/System.err(9310):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 11:19:05.324: I/TAG(9310): tryToListFarms response:[]
09-22 11:19:05.324: I/TAG(9310): false
09-22 11:19:05.324: I/TAG(9310): MyAsyncHttpRequest::doInBackground 0
09-22 11:19:05.324: I/TAG(9310): MyAsyncHttpRequest::doInBackground session=null
09-22 11:19:05.364: I/TAG(9310): MyAsyncHttpRequest::onPostExecute:onPostExecute result: null
09-22 11:19:05.364: D/AndroidRuntime(9310): Shutting down VM
09-22 11:19:05.364: W/dalvikvm(9310): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4156cba8)
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310): Process: com.XXX.start, PID: 9310
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at com.XXX.utils.MyAsyncHttpRequest.onPostExecute(MyAsyncHttpRequest.java:108)
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at com.XXX.utils.MyAsyncHttpRequest.onPostExecute(MyAsyncHttpRequest.java:1)
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-22 11:19:05.364: E/AndroidRuntime(9310):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: have you tried as `this.callback =act;` ?

Comment: It gets a compilation Error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Activity to AsyncTaskCompleteListener`

Comment: i'm pretty sure that you have wrong `imports` and AsyncTaskCompleteListener from this line `public class WmsMapActivity extends Activity implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener` is not the same as in this line `this.callback = (AsyncTaskCompleteListener)act;`

Comment: @Selvin `AsyncTaskCompleteListener` is in another Package and it is `public`, so, I didn't need to import but I have done as you suggested and I still get the same exception.

Comment: Please add full code of async task implementation

Comment: you are using imports ... at the begining of file ... `import com.XXX.utils.AsyncTaskCompleteListener;` ... try to use fully qualified name instead `AsyncTaskCompleteListener` use `com.XXX.utils.AsyncTaskCompleteListener` in both files

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK As I said, I would get a compilation error If I'd do it

Comment: @SuneelPrakash What I posted is just what crashes, rest of implementation works.

Comment: @Gödel77 : i have tested your case and my answer is working fine without `ClassCastException` in pointed line in question

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Just this, without changes?

Comment: @Selvin : you are right problem is probably with import.

Comment: I put that import in my Activity and in my `MyAsyncHttpRequest` Class and worked! Thanks all! Selvin, just write such an answer and I accept it.

Comment: Can I know, why I was downvoted and who did it?

Comment: here is an example why you get this ... http://ideone.com/Hn2YqM

Comment: @Selvin what you suggested with the imports in both of Classes (MyAsynHttpReques and WmsAMapActivity) worked, please, write it as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try cast in activity and receive interface object in AsyncTask.

```
public MyAsyncHttpRequest(AsyncTaskCompleteListener act, SessionManager session ) {
        try {
            Log.i("TAG", "MyAsyncHttpRequest::Constructor");
            this.activity = act;
            this.callback = act; // Just here crashes all!!!
            this.session  = session;

    } catch ( Exception exc ) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }


 = new MyAsyncHttpRequest(AsyncTaskCompleteListener.class.cast(this), session);
```

Comment: hm.. It's look like you not implemented interface. Maybe it's IDE bug, when last code not applied to build. Try rebuild project and clear cache. What IDE are you use ?

Comment: @smail123 Yes, I did it, please take a look at  `public class WmsMapActivity extends Activity implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener{...` and `onCompleteTask` implementation. Regards

Comment: Try declare AsyncTaskCompleteListener like inner static interface in AsyncTaskCompleteListener class.

Comment: I can already solve it, @Selvin has explained it, it was a trouble with the properly imports. Referred to your suggestion, I implement that interface in more Activities, so I prefer to have as outter interface in a separate file. Thx for suggestion anyway.